# How to Purge Eclipse from my Operating System?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I forked a maven project from a git repository to my Eclipse IDE then, Maven starts update the dependencies but, my IDE shut herself up.

How to purge Eclipse from my system, since Eclipse doesn't shows in the Uninstall Program of my Operating System.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Eclipse doesn't show in the installed programms, it means you have downloaded it and unzipped it. So just delete the directory where u have unzipped Eclipse.

Comment: plus(unless the op wants to archive) workspace + config directory + directory it installed it to (maybe also the m2 directories).

Comment: I'll try this. :D

Comment: @Tristan, I deleted the folders and reinstalled Eclipse but, shows the message when Maven update the project dependencies:

**
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'Framework Web'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:mave...
**

Comment: @Tristan I deleted the ".m2" folder from my profile and Updated the Maven project and problem solved. :D o/
Thank you for answer!